# Is Presto is a data store for storing data?

Tags: presto, trino

I am new to work on Presto. I have some doubts regarding Presto.

1. Whether Presto is a data store(database)?
2. If it is a query engine ?  Whether there is any common query syntax for accessing Hive, SQL, Cassandra data using connectors or it will accept all data source queries based on connectors ?
3. Where the query execution will takes place in Presto or in connected data source end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is a query engine. However it accesses data from many different data sources.
2. Yes. It is ANSI SQL. When accessing data from underlying data source then it's specific interface is used (thrift, hdfs, jdbc etc), but this is hidden from the user.
3. In both places. Presto is capable to push down some data filtering down to underlying data source (projection, where clauses). There is current effort to also push more parts of SQL query (see https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/18). Rest is evaluated in Presto.

Comment: which means Presto cannot be used as standalone data store. It should definitely need a third party data store like SQL Server or Hive or MySQL to access. Am I right.

Comment: If we insert data to presto it will be written to an underlying data store, is this correct?